# Why pg_dump.exe starts to generate so high utilization on C:\pagefile.sys?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, pg-dump

We have some strange situation on one client machine.
We have PostgreSQL 13 on Windows 10 (yeah do not blame me).

Machine have 16GB RAM.

When pg_dump.exe performs backup postgres.exe process uses disc to do the backup.
During the backup process I notice that postgres.exe is generate about 1MB/s drive utilization.
A the same time system generates even about 16MB/s drive utilization on C:\pagefile.sys

So i check RAM utilization and this it uses about 8GB RAM from 16GB instaled on the system.
So we had about another 8GB of FREE RAM, which is about 50% of total RAM instaled on the system.

My question is: Why pg_dump.exe starts to generate so high utilization on C:\pagefile.sys ?

Comment: Perhaps you have some large binary values or JSON data in some table, or you have lots of [large objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html).

Comment: some databases contain blobs. Usually, these are XML or PDF files or other types of files, saved as BLOBs, which as individual files usually do not exceed 1MB. In total, it can be up to 100 GB. Would this situation fit your guess?

Comment: I must add that these are not temporary increased resource consumption. Such a state of increased disk usgae on `pagefile.sys` may last for a long time, even for several minutes.

Comment: I have no idea how Windows manages its memory. But if you have a lot of large objects, the dump can use a lot of memory. That's one of the many reasons never to use large objects.

Comment: My concern is about: I have 8GB free RAM... so why pagefile.sys is used ?

Comment: That's a question for an operating system specialist. Perhaps you used more memory at some time?